# rails - NoMethodError in PostsController#create undefined method `post_url'

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm writing a simple website in which users (authenticated with Devise) can create posts. Upon creating a new post, I'm running into this error in which it won't redirect to the post. Here's my Posts controller:

```
class PostsController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :authenticate_user!

  def new
    @post = current_user.posts.new
  end

  def create
    @post = current_user.posts.new(post_params)
    if @post.save
      redirect_to @post
    end
  end

  def show
    @post = Post.find_by_id(params[:id])
  end

  private
    def post_params
      params.require(:post).permit(:title, :content)
    end
end
```

Here's my routes.rb:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  devise_for :users
  resources :users do
    resources :posts 
  end
  root 'posts#new'
end
```

Since the posts resource is nested within users I thought perhaps I should   have this in my controller:

```
if @post.save
      redirect_to current_user.@post
    end
```

But that produces a SyntaxError in PostsController#create error.

Can anyone see the problem that's preventing the controller from redirecting to the post after it's created? Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this -

```
redirect_to [current_user,@post]
```

OR,

```
redirect_to user_post_path(current_user, @post)
```

hope it helps!

Comment: This looks like it should work but now I get:

No route matches {:action=>"show", :controller=>"posts", :id=>nil, :user_id=>#<Post id: 10, user_id: "1", title: "Test! Test! This is a test!", content: "Test 1!", created_at: "2016-04-02 18:15:17", updated_at: "2016-04-02 18:15:17">} missing required keys: [:id]

For some reason it seems the id isn't being passed correctly.

Comment: @AdamLazarus yes, it is looking for user id. I have edited the answer, please try it once.

Comment: No luck! It still gives the same error. I tried it with [current_user, @post] too and that didn't work either. The error message says :id=>nil and missing required keys: [:id] so is it not a problem with the new post's id not being passed to the route correctly?

Comment: @AdamLazarus can you give it a try `redirect_to [current_user,@post]`

Comment: I figured it out! The route takes two parameters with the first being the user_id and the second being the id, so I needed `redirect_to user_post_path(current_user, @post)`. You got me there so I'll make this as the answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In your model, have you allowed for nested attributes? In the controller you want to use build instead of new.

Comment: Yes, I have. What would be the advantage of using build instead of new? I was under the impression that they're aliases of one another.